# Prevent buffer overflow when using cin.getline and fgets in conjugation

Tags: c++, string, stdin, buffer-overflow, istream

***The problem is that the size of strings is small. So the overflowing bits get assigned to next string.***

I recently came to know that we shouldn't use **fflush(stdin)** for discarding unwanted sequence in input stream when using **getline** as it has undefined behaviour. People recommend to use **cin.ignore()** instead.

But what should we use for ignoring unwanted sequence in input stream with **fgets**?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string cpp;
    char c1[6];
    char c2[5];

    // Reading C++ string: GETLINE
    getline( cin, cpp);

    // Reading C string: CIN.GETLINE
    cin.getline( c1, sizeof(c1) );

    // cin.ignore(); DOESNT WORK
    // fflush(stdin); UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR


    // Reading C string: FGETS
    fgets( c2, sizeof(c2), stdin);

    cout << " " << cpp << '\n' << c1 << '\n' << c2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example input, the observed output and the desired output.

Comment: @user2079303 Done. Actually the desired output is being able to input the string **c2**. Presently, overflown chars get stored into c2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the old fashioned [c way](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html) to skip the rest of the line using `getchar`.

```
char c;
while((c = std::getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```